# Recursive function to remove vowels

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a recursive program that returns a string of letters from a word that are non vowels. My code right now print's out all of the non vowels of "University" but never ends . Any ideas?

```
def removeVowels9(aString):
    if len(aString) == 0:
        return newString
    else:
        newString = aString[1:len(aString) + 1]
        firstLetter = aString[0]
        #print(firstLetter)
        if firstLetter in "aeiouAEIOU":

            return removeVowels9(newString)
        else:
            newString = newString + firstLetter
            print(newString)

            return removeVowels9(newString)
```

Comment: "".join([c for c in "UniversitY" if c.lower() not in 'aeiou']) gives 'nvrstY'

Comment: This is a really good way to hit maximum recursion depth. The technique you're using here is called "tail recursion" and it's not a good idea in languages that use a stack like Python.

Answer (score 6):

Clearly you are never hitting the base case, because you would get a `NameError` (`newString` hasn't been defined).

Why? Let's look at your third case:

```
else: # starts with consonant
    newString = newString + firstLetter # add first letter to the end?
    return removeVowels9(newString) # repeat
```

once you've removed all of the vowels, this just keeps on looping the consonants, as you should have seen from your outputs:

```
>>> removeVowels9("University")
iversityn
ersitynv
sitynvr
itynvrs
ynvrst # all vowels gone
nvrsty
vrstyn
rstynv
stynvr
tynvrs
ynvrst # just keeps looping
...
```

Here is the minimal fix:

```
>>> def removeVowels9(aString):
    if len(aString) == 0:
        return aString # aString, not newString
    else:
        newString = aString[1:len(aString) + 1]
        firstLetter = aString[0]
        #print(firstLetter)
        if firstLetter in "aeiouAEIOU":

            return removeVowels9(newString)
        else:
            return firstLetter + removeVowels9(newString) # add first letter back at start, after processing rest


>>> removeVowels9("University")
'nvrsty'
```

But this could be much neater:

```
def remove_vowels(s):
    """Recursively remove vowels from the input."""
    if not s: # empty string
        return s
    elif s[0] in "aeiouAEIOU": # first character is vowel
        return remove_vowels(s[1:]) # skip first character and process rest
    return s[0] + remove_vowels(s[1:]) # return first character and process rest
```

Which does:

```
>>> remove_vowels("University")
'nvrsty'
```

Note compatibility with [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for variable names etc..

Comment: Thanks for your help makes a lot more sense now! @jonrsharpe @